# Bootstrap Popover Form In Jquery Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, popover

I am using JQuery UI 1.12.1 and Bootstrap v3.3.7. I have a popover form that is a part of a dialog, and everything is functional except the user is unable to enter text into the popover form. If I move the popover form on the "main page" instead of in the dialog, the input works correctly.

This is the div that turns into the popover:

```
<div class="hide" id="owner-popover">
    <div id="owner-search-popover">
        <div class="row">
            <form class="form-inline" id="owner-search" name="owner-search">
                <label class="sr-only" for="ownerFirstNameSearch">First Name</label> 
                <input class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" name="FirstName" placeholder="First Name" type="text"> 
                <label class="sr-only" for="ownerLastNameSearch">Last Name</label> 
                <input class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" name="LastName" placeholder="Last Name" type="text"> 
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <table class="table table-condensed" id="owner-search-results">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="row owner-search-paginate"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <button class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 btn btn-primary bottomaligned" id="add-owner">Add Owner</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please see my code on jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/surm2jkj/

How do I enable my popover input to except text?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this functional by changing the dialog's modal option to false.

```
$("#add-element-dialog").dialog({
  autoOpen: false, 
  modal: false,
  height: 510,
  width: 650,
  resizable: false,
  buttons: {
    //OK: function() {$(this).dialog("close");}
  },
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/surm2jkj/1/

I would still like to find out how this can be done without setting the modal option to false.